# Scheduling hangfire jobs in a different project to where they are executed

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

I have 2 .net core web projects.
One of them is called ScheduledJobs and it uses Hangfire with the dashboard to both schedule and process jobs.
The other is called ClientWebsite and it schedules the jobs only - but I dont want them executing here!

ScheduledJobs works fine, if I schedule anything from there it picks them up and processes them.

But since I need to be able to schedule jobs from clientWebsite too, I have to have the following settings in startup:

services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
services.AddHangfireServer();

If I dont call services.AddHangfireServer it wont even let me schedule them.
But if I add it, then it processes them too which I dont want !

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to register the hangfire service at all in the second project in this way.

If you want to purely queue jobs from it you can use the GlobalConfiguration to set up which database it should point at similar to

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

Once you have done this you can register a BackgroundJobClient similar to this (this is taken from an autofac example so depending on your DI it wont be exactly the same as the line below)

```
builder.RegisterType<BackgroundJobClient>().As<IBackgroundJobClient>();
```

What this then allows you to do is resolve and enqueue jobs using the IBackgroundJobClient in your application without setting up a hangfire server at all.

In your classes where you want to enqueue jobs from you can then simple resolve an instance of IBackgroundJobClient and make use of the `Enqueue` method such as

`_myClient.Enqueue<MyJobClass>(x => x.APublicMethodOnMyJobClass());`

Details on the backgroundjobclient can be found here - [BackgroundJobClient](https://api.hangfire.io/html/T_Hangfire_BackgroundJobClient.htm)